# Output a WooCommerce product custom field in WooCommerce using get_post_meta()

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a plugin to display schema script for my WooCommerce product. I use a custom field to add my gtin number in WooCommerce.

This is what I did:

```
<?php
    $gtin = get_post_meta(post_ID,'gtin',true);
?>
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "gtin13:"<?php echo $gtin;?>"</script>}
```

The result:

```
"gtin13:"1112223334"
```

Which work fine…

But sometime products doesn't have `gtin` number, so I created function like this:

1. go check if there is gtin number or not?
2. If don't echo "identifier_exit:false"
3. If found gtin number echo "gtin13:gtin number"

```
     <?php
         function check_gtin() {
             $gtin=get_post_meta(post_ID,'gtin',true);
             if ($gtin!='') {
                 echo '$gtin13:$gtin';
             } else {
                 echo 'identifier_exits:false';
             }
         }
     ?>
    <script type="application/json+ld">{
        "<?php check_gtin();?>"</script>}
```

The result:

```
"gtin13:$gtin"
```

What I am expecting:

```
"gtin13:1112223334"
```

So can someone point to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors as `get_post_meta()` first argument need to be a defined product ID here (and in your code `post_ID` is not even dynamic variable and will not give anything)…

Try the following:

```
<?php
     function check_gtin(){
         if ( $gtin = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'gtin', true) ){
             echo "gtin13:". $gtin;
         } else {
             echo 'identifier_exits:false';
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Then:

```
<script type="application/json+ld">{"<?php check_gtin(); ?>"</script>
```

It should better work…

Comment: Anyway to use get_post_meta in the WC cart?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you need to pass the $post_id to the function so it has something to work with.

```
global $post;

check_gtin( $post->ID );

function check_gtin( $post_id ) { /* ... */ }
```

---

Another problem is that in PHP single quotes are meant to be [literal strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and will not print the variables in them. There's a couple ways to convert this into working code:

## [Double Quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

```
echo "gtin13:{$gtin}";
```

## [String Concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo 'gtin13:' . $gtin;
```

## [Formatted Printing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf( 'gtin13:%s', $gtin );
```

---

Additionally, depending on how you're setting the post meta it could return something "empty" but not necessary an empty string `''`. Personally, I prefer to use [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if something exists. This will check for empty arrays, empty strings, 0, false.

---

To bring it altogether, it could look like:

```
/**
 * Display GTIN
 *
 * @param Integer $post_id
 *
 * @return void
 */
function check_gtin( $post_id ) {

    $gtin = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gtin', true );

    if( ! empty( $gtin ) ) {
        echo "gtin13:{$gtin}";
    } else {
        echo 'identifier_exits:false';
    }

}
```